# Calling function into another function scipy.minimize. missing 3 required positional arguments:

Tags: python, function, scipy, data-science

I want to understand how to call another function into function. For example, I want to approximate data by rational function, so I want to minimize approximation function. I use

```
def rational(a, b, c, d, x):
    return (a * x + b) / (x ** 2 + c * x + d)

def approximate(a, b, c, d, x, y, func):
    return np.sum( (func(a, b, c, d, x) - y) ** 2 )
```

I want to pass `rational` into `approximate` and after that pass it to `scipy.minimize` like

```
minimize(approximate, x0=(0, 0, 0, 0), args=(X, Y, rational,), method='Nelder-Mead')
```

But the error is appear: `approximate() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'x', 'y', and 'func'`

So I want to understand how I should work with such constructions and best practices with working to

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a function with 7 arguments to `minimize`, but it expects a function with signature `fun(x, *args)`. If you really want to pass the additional function arguments by `minimize`'s args parameter, you can do something like this:

```py
minimize(lambda z, *args: approximate(*z, *args), x0=(0, 0, 0, 0), args=(X, Y, rational), method='Nelder-Mead')
```

Here, `*z` unpacks all arguments. However, a much cleaner solution would be:

```py
minimize(lambda z: approximate(*z, X, Y, rational), x0=(0, 0, 0, 0), method='Nelder-Mead')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using `a, b, c, d = params` into functions.
Working code is

```
def rational(params, x):
    a, b, c, d = params
    return (a * x + b) / (x ** 2 + c * x + d)

def approximate(params, x, y, func):
    return np.sum( (func(params, x) - y) ** 2 )

nm_coefs = minimize(approximate, x0=(0, 1, 3, 2), args=(X, Y, rational,), method='Nelder-Mead')
```